# How to check a website is running over http or https (protocol)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a http call from angular js.
I am not sure about the protocol of the target website.So I want to know the protocol(http/https) of the target site.
My code looks like this.

```
var Path12 = "https://ABC.azurewebsites.net/XYZPage/XYZ_FUNCTION";
$http.get(Path12).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  var abc = "";
  var pqr = "";
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
```

I want to check this ABC.azurewebsites.net is running on http or https.

Comment: use `Path12.slice(0,5)` and compare it

Comment: Guys... he wants to know if the webserver *actually* serves over https, not if the url contains https....... Anyway, I think each webserver would respond to that differently. I remember weblogic and tomcat showing weird behavior when querying https content over http

Comment: As @Sebas said I want if the webserver actually serves over https, not if the url contains https.

Comment: I think that in any case if https is not served, you will not get a 200 status response (but request might return successfully tho). I'm 99% certain of it. (the 1% remaining is the reason why I don't post this as an answer :P)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anchor link.

```
var Path12 = "https://ABC.azurewebsites.net/XYZPage/XYZ_FUNCTION";
var link = $document.createElement('a');
link.href = Path12;
console.log(link.protocol) //http:||https:
```

Checkout: https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

Edit:
You can also use the `URL` class.

```
var link = new URL(Path12)
{href: "https://abc.azurewebsites.net/XYZPage/XYZ_FUNCTION", origin: "https://abc.azurewebsites.net", protocol: "https:", username: "", password: ""…}
```

Comment: @Deliaz oops Fixed.

Comment: I tried this but it is not giving me the protocol of the site.It returns the same      protocol whatever I have passed in the href.Like if I call a http:// something  it returns http only.

Comment: be careful about relative vs absolute urls.
if url doesn't start with http:// than the url is considered to be relative url.